# Registrar mysqli en php

Tags: php, mysqli

Hola amigos tengo una pregunta. Tengo una tabla con datos que coinciden y datos que no. Quiero saber si puedo registrar un comentario para los que deben y guardar los datos en otra tabla llamada deuda. y que al presionar un botón (validado) se guardarán los datos en una tabla llamada validados.

Aquí mi código:

---

**index.php**

```js
<?php
    require_once ("./app/conexion.php");
    session_start();
    // Establece los mensajes de sesion
    $_SESSION['message'] = "";
    //Valida si es enviado por post
    //Valida si es enviado por post
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if (isset($_POST['deuda'])) { // aqui me introduce los datos en registro empleados
            require_once './app/deuda.php'; //requiere de registro empleados
        } 
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pagos Listos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Administradores Registrados</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="continer-alerta"> 
            <div style="color:#fff;"class="mensaje-alerta">
                <?php echo $_SESSION['message'] ?> 
            </div>
                </br></br>
        </div>    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Aqui se visualizara los pagos validos y los no validos
                    </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form>
                                <table method="post" action="#" width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example" >
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Ticket</th>
                                            <th>Usuario</th>
                                            <th>Cedula</th>
                                            <th>Referencia</th>
                                            <th>Monto</th>
                                            <th>Estatus</th>
                                            <th>Reportado</th>
                                            <th>Comentario</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <?php
                                    //Clase para manejar la conexion a la base de datos
                                    class Connect
                                    {
                                        private $user = "root";//usuario de mysqlk
                                        private $pass = "";//clave de mysql
                                        private $base = "radius";//base de datos en mysql
                                        private $server = "localhost";//servidor de alojamiento
                                        public  $error;//en caso de error se almacena aqui
                                        public  $db;
                                        public  function __construct(){
                                            $mysqli = new mysqli($this->server, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->base);
                                            if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                                                $this->error = "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
                                            }
                                            $this->db = $mysqli;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    //Clase trabajo que se extiende de Connect
                                    class Trabajo extends Connect
                                    {
                                        public function __construct(){
                                            parent::__construct();
                                        }
                                        public function valida($x){
                                                $a = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM archivos_pagos WHERE referencia = '$x' ");
                                                
                                        $t = $a->num_rows;

                                                if($t>=1){
                                                    //Si el cliente realizó el pago retorno la información
                                                    $row = $a->fetch_object();
                                                    return $row;
                                                }else{
                                                    //si no retorno falso
                                                    return false;
                                                }
                                        }//
                                        public function data(){
                                            $a = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM pagos_pagina");
                                            $con=1;
                                            while($row = $a->fetch_object()){
                                                //Envío a validar la referencia del cliente
                                                $valida = $this->valida($row->referencia);
                                               
                                                
                                                if($valida){                           
                                        echo "<tr> 
                                            <td>".$con."</td>
                                            <td>".$row->nombre." ".$row->apellido."</td>
                                            <td>".$row->cedula."</td>
                                            <td>".$valida->referencia."</td>
                                            <td>".$row->monto."</td>
                                            <td>Valido</td>
                                            <td><a href='#'> <butoon type='button' class='btn btn-success'>Valido</button></a></td>
                                            <td><div class='panel-footer'>
                                            <div class='input-group'>
                                                <input id='btn-input 'type='text' class='form-control input-sm' placeholder='Escribe un Comentario' />
                                                <span class='input-group-btn'>
                                                    <button class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' id='btn-chat'> Enviar </button>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div></td>

                                        </tr>";
                                    }else{
                                        echo "<tr>
                                                <td>".$con."</td>
                                                <td>".$row->nombre." ".$row->apellido."</td>
                                                <td>".$row->cedula."</td>
                                                <td>".$row->referencia."</t>
                                                <td>".$row->monto."</t>
                                                <td>Invalido</td>
                                                <td><a href='#'> <butoon type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Invalido</button></a></td>
                                                <td><div class='panel-footer'>
                                                    <div class='input-group'>
                                                        <input id='btn-input 'type='text' class='form-control input-sm' placeholder='Escribe un Comentario' />
                                                        <span class='input-group-btn'>
                                                            <button class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' id='btn-chat'> Enviar </button>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div></td>
                                            </tr>";
                                            } 
                                            $con++;
                                            }
                                            echo "</table>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    $p = new trabajo();
                                    $p->data();
                                    ?>
                                </table>
                            </form>    
                        </div>    
                    </div>    
                </div>               
            </div> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**app/config.ini**

```js
[database]
username = root
password = 
dbname = radius
```

---

**app/conexion.php**

```js
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $config = parse_ini_file('./security/config.ini');

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['dbname']);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
?>
```

---

**app/deuda.php**

```js
<?php
    $ticket = $conn->escape_string($_POST['ticket']);
    $usuario = $conn->escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
    $cedula = $conn->escape_string($_POST['cedula']);
    $referencia = $conn->escape_string($_POST['referencia']);
    $monto = $conn->escape_string($_POST['monto']);
    $estatus = $conn->escape_string($_POST['estatus']);
    $telefono = $conn->escape_string($_POST['telefono']);
    $comentario = $conn->escape_string($_POST['comentario']);

            $sql = 
                "INSERT INTO deuda (
                    ticket, 
                    usuario, 
                    cedula, 
                    referencia, 
                    monto,
                    estatus,
                    telefono,
                    comentario
                    ) 
                    "."
                    VALUES (
                        '$ticket',
                        '$usuario',
                        '$cedula',
                        '$referencia',
                        '$monto',
                        '$estatus',
                        '$telefono',
                        '$comentario'
                )";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
                    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Su comentario a sido guardado ';
                } else {
                    // Devuelve un mensaje de error
                    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Ocurrio un error al guardar su comentario';
                 }
```

---

Todas las tablas tienen los mismos campos.

Comment: alam hola, esto es un comentario de consejo no de solución a tu pregunta , pero seria buena practica que separes la conexion de la vista , estarías mostrando datos sensibles en una vista principal.Saludos.

Comment: sebastian como asi de la vista explicate mejor porfa

Comment: lo que pasa es que tienes la clase conect en el index.php, o sea tienes los datos de registro de tu bd en la vista y no es muy buena practica tenerlos ahí.Lo ideal sería que en otro archivo php , llamado por ejemplo connect.php algo asi y de ahi hacer un include en index.php del el archivo connect que creaste.

Comment: exelente entendido sebastian asi lo hare gracias